# v-container is not applying the container behavior

Tags: vuetify.js

I included Vuetify 2(latest) in my Vue project. I am trying to do some grids with cards inside of a container and it does apply container fluid behavior without including fluid.

Here is my App.vue[image]

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app>
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
        <span>Vuetify</span>
        <span class="font-weight-light">MATERIAL DESIGN</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn
        text
        href="https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/latest"
        target="_blank"
      >
        <span class="mr-2">Latest Release</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-content>
       <v-layout>

  <v-container videos-content grid-list-md >
    <v-layout wrap>
      <v-flex v-for="video in videos" :key="video.id" xs12 sm6 md3>
        <v-card max-width="344" class="mx-auto">
          <v-card-title>{{video.title}}</v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>{{video.description}}</v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <a target="_blank" :href="video.url">open in Youtube</a>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
  </v-layout>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the correct structure of vuetify layout is `v-container` >> `v-layout` >> `v-flex`

So maybe remove `v-layout` tag defined outside of `v-container`?

Though not quite sure what you meant by 'fluid behavior'...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine, you just need to follow standard structure from vuetify documentation. I made a [pen](https://codepen.io/rveruna/pen/wvwMNmP) for you

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <template>
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
        <span>Vuetify</span>
        <span class="font-weight-light">MATERIAL DESIGN</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn>
        <span class="mr-2">Latest Release</span>
      </v-btn>
  <v-container grid-list-md >
    <v-layout wrap>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 md3>
        <v-card max-width="344" class="mx-auto">
          <v-card-title></v-card-title>
          <v-card-text></v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <a>open in Youtube</a>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
</div>
```